Are a Z80 address pins tristate?
I been looking at the Z80 CPU recently and am wondering how difficult it would be to wire one up. The thing I'm interested in is how to connect it to some RAM. In particular, I'd like to know if the address line go tristate when the CPU is neither reading or writing memory (or IO).
Most of the website I've looked at say nothing about it, but I did find one that claims the address bus is tristate. Initially I was happy with that (it's always nice to hear the answer you'd like to be given), but.... then I started to wonder why Zilog would make these lines tristate. As the Z80 predates modern the DMA controllers, I can't think of anything else that would want to take control the address bus. So why would Zilog make the CPU more complex than it needs to be?

The Z80 address pins are tristate pins. But they only enter high impedance state when you successfully arbitrate for the bus using BUSREQ. See e.g. http://www.z80.info/zip/z80.pdf PDF page 25.

The Intel 8237 DMA controller which still lives on in quite a number of modern  PC chipsets (so, it must be a "modern" one) was introduced together with the 8080, so easily pre-dates the Z80. Your presumptions are wrong. Also note that DMA doesn't necessarily mean "DMA controller". A lot of peripheral devices (floppy controllers, for example) can potentially take over the bus and write to memory directly.


I'd like to know if the address line go tristate when the CPU is neither reading or writing memory (or IO).

No, they don't. At least not until the CPU is asked to release the bus - wihch is what /BUSREQ is for. Mentioned on page 9 of the 1977 manual:

(From Page 9 of the 1977 Z80 CPU Technical Manual)
As seen, not just address signals, which on it's own would be rather pointless, but all bus signals are tristated, once the bus is handed over.
The Manual continues on page 14..16 with an in detail description and several fine timing diagrams.

Most of the website I've looked at say nothing about it, but I did find one that claims the address bus is tristate.

Why waste time reading third hand information on the web when one can read the original data sheets and manuals? (*1) They should always be the first go-to for question about any chip.

As the Z80 predates modern the DMA controllers,

Not so sure what a 'modern' should mean here, but DMA controllers do predate the Z80 by far. After all, the Z80 is an improved 8080, which provides 8257 and 8237 DMA controllers. Both usable with the later Z80 Except teh Z80 family provided it's own as well, conveniantly named Z80 DMA.

I can't think of anything else that would want to take control the address bus.

Another CPU, some Video logic, some discrete DMA like from data recording and so on. endless possibilities, even more than nowadays, as timing was way more tight back then.

So why would Zilog make the CPU more complex than it needs to be?

The Z80 is an upward/replacement design for the 8080, so it was mandatory to support everything the 8080 could do, no matter if it's signals, basic bus timing and sequence or features like interrupt handling.

*1 - IIRC it was Leonardo Da Vinci who wrote something along the line of one who can drink from the source should not dring from a stale pot.

Yes, the Z80 can tristate its address bus, but only as the result of arbitration via BUSREQ.
And there certainly were DMA controllers, both for the Z80 specifically, and generic ones that predated it.
The whole concept of DMA for I/O and multiple CPUs sharing the same memory came long before the development of the microprocessor.
